# Front Matter in a Work in Two Volumes

Tags: formatting

I am writing a thesis, and the material of said work naturally splits into two self-consistent volumes. Which front matter (abstract, preface, dedication, synopsis, table of contents, list of tables/figures, etc.) should remain the same between the two volumes and which should differ (or stand alone with specific material to that volume)?

Answer (score 2):

The answer really depends on how your content is split. If you look at the entire work, I would recommend keeping the abstract, the preface, and the dedication in the first volume. Both volumes would have their own table of contents and list of tables, etc. to specify the actual content in each book.

If each book is diversified enough to be consider as two distinctly separate topics, then you might consider having a separate abstract, preface, and deication for each book. Either way, they should both have their own distinct TOC and list of tables.

Comment: TOC can be shared